# Set value to a new created (named ID) attribute for an Excel writer with number format in FME

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer

I modified the schema of my Excel writer and now I have some new attributes one of which is ID and it must be number. Then I added an attribute manager to set value to my new attribute. I am trying to find a way to fill new field (attribute) with correct value and format. It looks simple but I can't find it.

Comment: Is it in the AttributeManager that you are having a problem? Or in the writer schema?

Comment: I created a new empty attribute in the writer but I don't know how to set values. My problem is in AttributeManager. I am not sure if it's a proper transformer or I have to find another one.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your Attributes Definition to Manual if you wish to have control over it.

[image]

I will be set automatically as a number once it has reached the writer.